# HTTPRequest solution needed

Tags: php, xml

Hallo,

I need to send a request to a page (POST) and then, I will read the XML and take the logical action.

How can I best send from my PHP request and then read the response.
Thnkas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from  within your php you can use HttpRequest::send
http://usphp.com/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php
there are other options too like curl or others.

All of them has a kind of send() method, which will send the request and return the response to you. Than you can parse the response with XMLWriter or other.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the curl library to send the POST request: http://php.net/curl

Answer (score 0):

You need a HTTP Client for your PHP code. There's one [here](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is make a simple POST request then no need to use complicated solutions based on curl. PHP streams will support it just fine.

```
$xml = file_get_contents(
    $url,
    null,
    stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST'
        )
    ))
);
```

Then you can use [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to read the XML.